# AutoHoyKey: Send text when press WINKEY + L

Tags: string, windows-10, autohotkey

Whe I press this combination :

```
WINKEY + L
```

I want to be written this:

```
LIKE '%%'
```

I tried to do this, but doesn't work:

```
<#l::
Send , (LIKE '%%')
```

I accept suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any braces `(`,  `)` in commands  like `Send`.

And,`%` has a special meaning in AutoHotkey, see https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#esc.

And iyou should always end your hotkeys, labels, hotstrings, with a `return` to indicate the end of it.

Use:

```
<#l::
Send, LIKE'`%`%'
return
```